# why two function gives different output having same approch?

Tags: javascript

**below function gives incorrect output**

```
function searchFn(obj, searchText) {
    let result;
    if (obj.name === searchText) return obj;
    if (obj['children'] && obj['children'].length > 0) {
        obj['children'].forEach((i) => {
                 result = searchFn(i, searchText);
                 return result
        })
    }
    return result || null
}
```

**Below function gives correct out**

```
function searchFn(object, searchText) {
    var result;
    if (object.name === searchText) return object;
    (object.children || []).some((o) =>{
        result = searchFn(o, searchText)
        return result
    });
    return result || null;
}
```

why it is happening ?I used on `forEach` in first approch and `some` function in second .

any body explain why it is happening?

```
let tree = { name: "A", children: [{ name: 'A-1', children: [{ name: "A-1-A" }, { name: "A-1-B" }] }, { name: 'B-1', children: [{ name: "B-1-A", children: [{ name: "B-11-A" }, { name: "B-11-B" }] }, { name: "B-1-B" }] }] };


console.log(searchFn(tree, 'A-1'));
```

expected output is

**{ name: 'A-1', children: [{ name: "A-1-A" }, { name: "A-1-B" }] }**

is first function i am getting **null**

second function gives correct output why ?

both function using recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `forEach` is ignored. In your first code, you're iterating through the whole structure recursively, but the `result` variable returned inside the `forEach` doesn't do anything - at the end, outside the loop, the `return result || null` will return only the result of calling `searchFn` for the final item in `obj.children`.

If you want to be able to return a recursive call directly, either use your `.some` method to short-circuit, or use a `for` loop, which you can `return` inside of to terminate the parent function:

```
function searchFn(object, searchText) {
  if (object.name === searchText) return object;
  if (!object.children) return;
  for (const child of object.children) {
    const result = searchFn(o, searchText)
    if (result) return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` executes without breaking the loop. As you are assigning `result`, it always receives the last value of the item.

on the other hand `.some` will stop the loop when some condition matches and returns `true`. so here `result` will receive the value when the condition matches and just before exiting the loop